# Remove class on keypress (after key hold), transitionend weird behavior

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am refactoring JS30 Challange #1. When key is pressed script adds a class to an element with a little transform. I want to remove class from an element when transition ends and I made this:

```
const KEYS = document.querySelectorAll('.audiobox');
KEYS.forEach(KEY => KEY.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  KEY.classList.remove('playing');
}), false);
```

This code works well but I wanted to clean up this by calling  removeTransition function.

```
function removeTransition(e) {
  if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
  e.target.classList.remove('playing');
}

const KEYS = document.querySelectorAll('.audiobox');
KEYS.forEach(KEY => KEY.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
```

When I press a key  script does its job, class is removed when transition ends but the problem is when I hold a key for few seconds class is never removed. As I mentioned, first solution works really well even  when I hold a key, the second one is not fully working, can you tell me why?

Here is whole script

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  function removeTransition(e) {
    if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    e.target.classList.remove('playing');
  }

  function playAudio(e) {
    let key_code;
    if (e.type === 'keydown') key_code = e.keyCode;
    if (e.type === 'click') key_code = e.target.getAttribute('data-key');
    const KEY   = document.querySelector('.audiobox[data-key="' + key_code + '"]');
    const AUDIO = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="' + key_code + '"]');

    if (!AUDIO) return;

    AUDIO.currentTime = 0;
    AUDIO.play();
    KEY.classList.add('playing');

    const KEYS = document.querySelectorAll('.audiobox');
    KEYS.forEach(KEY => KEY.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));

    // This one is working
    // KEYS.forEach(KEY => KEY.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    //   KEY.classList.remove('playing');
    // }), false);
  }

  window.addEventListener('keydown', playAudio);
  const BOXES = document.querySelectorAll('.audiobox');
  BOXES.forEach(BOX => BOX.addEventListener('click', playAudio));
})();
```

Comment: Are you getting any error when you choose second method in the console, also can you share the html / working code snippet

Comment: No errors in the console. Here you can check live version of the task http://fdev.pw/learnjs/js30/01/

Comment: why are you checking for `if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;' inside the function, but not when you are using the other code. Because of this, it is returning if the propertyName is box-shadow or any other than transform

Comment: Here is one code snippet I worked on based on your code. It worked for me . https://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/arkqdojs/4/ , after I removed the transform check

Comment: Oh, you're right. I forgot about the box-shadow which is also a propertyName of TransitionEvent and is added to my css file.

Comment: Cool, I will answer with above solution then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments,

remove the check `if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;` inside the removeTransition function

```
function removeTransition(e) {
 //   if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    e.target.classList.remove('playing');
  }
```

[Working code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/arkqdojs/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Seem like it's from Wesbos tut, I had same issue as you when tried to made a piano after that, if somebody would have same problem just use Settimeout function, like that:

```
function removeTransition(e) {

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.classList.remove('playing');
    }, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tutorial, the `if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;` was there because there were 6 transitionend events:

1. border-bottom-color
2. border-left-color
3. border-right-color
4. border-top-color
5. box-shadow
6. transform

By having it on our code, we'll only execute once rather than 6 times. So what I did instead to remove the .playing class is I added a keyup event listener so that even if I hold a key for a few seconds, it will still remove the class after.

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => keyFunc(e));
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => keyFunc(e));

function keyFunc(e){
  let dataKey = e.keyCode;
  const key = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${dataKey}"]`);

  if(e.type == 'keyup'){
    removeClass(e, key);
  }
  else if(e.type == 'keydown') {
    playSound(e, key);
  }
}

function playSound(e, key) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);

  if (key == null) return;
  key.classList.add('playing');
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();
}

function removeClass(e, key) {
  if (key == null) return;
  key.classList.remove('playing');
}

const div = document.querySelector("div");
div.addEventListener('transitionend', (e) => removeTransition(e));


function removeTransition(e) {
  if(e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    console.log(e);
    e.target.classList.remove('playing');
}

</script>
```